# reseting a ListView after the adapter's data was changed

Tags: android, listview, reset

I have a list view that can display items based on internal state (it
has items, and 'viewed' items). i need to be able to toggle between the
two states, i do that using a simple button that change the adapter's
state and the adapter then called notifyDatasetChanged().
My data DOES gets updated, however i was facing two problems:

1. if in the previous mode the list was partially scrolled, it stayed
   in that state after i changed the data set (if i was half the way down
   i'll be half way down in the new data set as well, this is not the
   behavior i want, but i cols not find a way to scroll the list manually
   to position 0. any ideas ? (setSelected is not exactly a solution since i DON'T want any selection i want to stay in touch mode)
2. In my list View each item has an image that is fetched from the
   net, as so it's being brought using my networking manager and i send
   the image request ONLY if i'm in this screen for the first time OR if
   scroll state is idlle, i didn't want to start loading images from the
   getView method since if i fling the screen it may load a lot of
   unnecessary images. However when calling notifyDatasetChanged() the
   scroll listener methods are not called. i solved this one by using
   notifyDatasetInvalidated even though my data is not empty, is there a
   better way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

regarding #1 it's my mistake i didn't read the documentation all the way through apparently, if i'm currently in touch mode no selection will be made, so the job is done by setSelectedPosition().

Regarding #2 i'm still not sure notifyDatasetInvalidated is the solution to make sure onScroll methods will be called.